# Reduce watchers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a 2D map with Angular JS. Basically, I receive a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
map: [
  40 : [
    40: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' },
    41: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' },
    ...,
    45: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' }
  ],
  41 : [
    40: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' },
    41: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' },
    ...,
    45: { obj1: [], obj2: [], obj3: [], obj4: [], prop1: 'x', prop2: 'y' }
  ],
  ...
];
```

I'm using this array and ng-repeat in order to display a 2D map, so if the user can see 5 cases away, I display a 11x11 map. Moreover, on each location [ (40 - 41), (40 - 42), etc], I display some counters which are the property "length" of "obj1", "obj2", "obj3" and "obj4".

All of this works quite well, but I'm a bit concerned about performances. I'm using one-way binding where I can but at the end of the day, the whole map is using 1400 watchers. This is quite OK but the user could see at more than a distance of 5. If it displays the map to see at a distance of 10, the map will be 21x21 => way lot more watchers...

I already Googled some way to improve that but I don't really know how I could reduce the watchers count. The thing is, to refresh the view, I'm really refreshing the whole array, so my idea would be to make the top binding "two-way" and the rest "one-way" (the child elements), this way, when the whole table content changes, the binding is made again but no watchers are defined for the diffrentes map cases.

I also see that I could use a ng-if but the HTML corresponding to the map can be quite consequent (especially for a 21x21 map), so I'd like to avoid manipulating the DOM this way.

Would someone have an idea for this ?

Comment: Just out of curiousity have you tried this with angular2 to test performance?

Comment: No no yet, the project is "too big" and angularjs 2 is not yet ready (in my opinion) to migrate the project. It is indeed planned but I'd like a solution for AngularJS 1.x first.

Comment: are you using `track by` in those `ng-repeat`?? and as you said use one-time binding in the childs items of the repeat